# Sanitation of user supplied json data needed?

Tags: php, json

I'm writing a script which takes user supplied Json files runs it through json_decode($string, true) and prints the arrayvalues. Looking at the $GLOBALS array I found out that the CMS I'm using(Drupal 7) is exposing db credentials in plain text.

Is there a way that somebody can inject code like var_dump($GLOBALS) via a supplied JSON file? Do i need to check the array supplied via json_decode for malicious code?

Example Code:

```
<?php
$jsTestString = '{ "identifier":{"inject":var_dump($GLOBALS) }}';
$jsonTestArray = json_decode($jsTestString, true);
print($jsonTestArray['identifier']['inject']);
// this thankfully doesn't work
```

Comment: It depends on what you do with the data. Your example is not valid JSON.

Comment: I run the json file through json_decode to write everything into an array and then print the values via print()

The example was for demonstrating how i thought there could be an attack vector. To generalize is there a way to inject php code via a json file

Comment: That should generally be safe. PHP is not going to just execute any functions written in a json file. It will read them as strings. Just don't run arbitrary user data through the `exec` function. And when printing to the screen, you should use `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Code injection can happen when you compose code dynamically (SQL, HTML, shell commands...). JSON by itself is not a programming or markup language, it's just data.